# modify / edit a PDF

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

I want to edit a shown pdf.

Currently I render one special PDF page by

*CGPDFDocumentRef* and *CGPDFPageRef*.

Now, simply I'm going to add a transparent **image** onto the **whole current page**. After the image has been added, I want to write it back into the **same file**.

But the PDF could be **multi paged** as well.

My actual approach for that would be to show the PDF as usual by *CGPDFPageRef* and render it.

For adding that special image I would use *UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData*.

Now I must only know, how to get the PDF data of the not modified pdf and inject that into *UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData*.

Then I would add that image into the context and write it into file.

Am I right so far or should I do it by another approach.

Here is my current code example:

```
//find a solution to inject the current shown page / current pdf document as pdfData


UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, a4Page, nil); 


CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

[pdfData writeToFile:newFilePath atomically:YES];
[fileMetaData release];
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to your question? If yes, can you post it for future readers?