# Write on a PDF file programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I'm looking for a way to write text on PDF file in my code.
I started with load the pdf file in a UIWebView and I add UILabel to the UIScrollView of the UIWebView. Is it the good way to write on it?
How can I save it with the modifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is built in API for [parsing PDF's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101):

However, I am not sure whether it allows to save modifications.
You may be interested to take a look at this question:

[how to edit a PDF in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333710/how-to-edit-a-pdf-in-objective-c)

[modify / edit a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249376/modify-edit-a-pdf)

[Edit PDF in iphone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331791/edit-pdf-in-iphone-application)

Alos, Look at following libraries (they are commercial):

- [PSPDFKit](http://pspdfkit.com/)
- [iAnnotate](http://www.branchfire.com/developers/)